# Yarn error during installation of roots-sage "No files matching the pattern"

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, yarnpkg, roots-sage

I've created a completely new wordpress project by getting the latest wordpress version and then creating a theme with Roots-sage. This is the documentation I followed: https://roots.io/docs/sage/9.x/installation/

and after the installation steps, I run **yarn start** (I've also tried **yarn build**) and I get this error:

> No files matching the pattern "{my-projects-assets-map}***.s?(c|a)ss" were found

Immediatly after running the 2 commands that are the first 2 steps:

```
composer create-project roots/sage your-theme-name
```

in the themes directory and

```
yarn
```

in the newly created theme, I already get this error. Right after the `yarn` command in the documentation, it says:

> You now have all the necessary dependencies to run the [build](https://roots.io/docs/sage/9.x/compiling-assets/#available-build-commands) process.

I have the dependencies as listed in the installation page:

- WordPress >= 4.7
- PHP >= 7.1.3 (with php-mbstring enabled)
- Composer
- Node.js >= 8.0.0
- Yarn

I have:

- Yarn 1.22.4
- PHP 7.4.8
- Node.js 15.2.1
- Wordpress 5.3.3
- Composer 1.10.8

I have found similar questions here on stackoverflow but not a real solution thats working for me.

Is there any way I can get more information on how to solve this and whats going wrong? Or does anyone know the solution by just seeing the information I provided?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with ESlint. I commented out the condition that throws the error on line 211 on the standalone.js file of the stylelint library inside node_modules. It allowed me to run yarn start, and it still compiles my styles.

Comment: When I remove this, it does allow me to run yarn start, however the page that opens just keeps loading. Forever.